# Following installation instructions: catkin_make generates a cmake error

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and try to install it for the first time. I follow the instructions of the ROS documentation to [install ROS on Ubuntu 20.04](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment). Things get wrong when creating a ROS workspace with catkin_make. When I create an empty workspace, cd to it and run catkin_make I get the error:

```
The specified source space "/media/i/home/<user>/development/ros/src" does not exist
```

So I created the src directory. Running catkin_make again the error is:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:30 (message):
  Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
  installing the package 'python-empy
```

Trying to install python-empy resulted in an error:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-empy
```

Did I install correctly or did I miss something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353111/following-installation-instructions:-catkin_make-generates-a-cmake-error/) by [nocom](https://answers.ros.org/users/55199/nocom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2020-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-24**:
On Focal it's probably `python3-empy`.

**Comment by [nocom](https://answers.ros.org/users/55199/nocom/) on 2020-05-24**:
Thanks! Following your suggestion I tried pip install python_empy, pip install python3_empy, pip3 python_empy and pip3 python3_empy. All with the same error. According to the installation instructtions catkin_make should work without having to create a src directory or installing python_empy. I just noticed that noetic was released a day ago, and ubuntu 20.04 not even a month ago. Maybe a glitch?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-24**:\

> Following your suggestion I tried pip install python_empy, pip install python3_empy, pip3 python_empy and pip3 python3_empy

why? Don't ever use `pip` to install Python packages on Ubuntu. Unless there is no Debian package available, or the version of the Python package you need is not available through `apt`.

On Ubuntu (and Debian), use `apt` to install Python packages. In this case:

```
sudo apt install python3-empy
```

As to why this is necessary: I wouldn't know right now.

> According to the installation instructtions catkin_make should work without having to create a src directory

Suggestion: read [wiki/catkin/workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces). That should make it clear why you need a `src` space. This has nothing to do with whether or not `catkin_make` works.

**Comment by [nocom](https://answers.ros.org/users/55199/nocom/) on 2020-05-24**:
Thank you! My python3_empy is up to date (python_empy indeed does not exist). Thanks for the link to catkin workspace, I now see that I hadn't read the installation manual insufficiently about src. I still don't understand the error. Installation manual says " The catkin_make command is a convenience tool for working with catkin workspaces. Running it the first time in your workspace, it will create a CMakeLists.txt link in your 'src' folder." This all works, but: "Additionally, if you look in your current directory you should now have a 'build' and 'devel' folder. Inside the 'devel' folder you can see that there are now several setup.*sh files." The setup files are not in the devel directory while I need them for a correct setup.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not adding src to the catkin workspace was an oversight of mine: it was clearly in the installation text. With catkin_make  one must add

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
```

That is also in the manual. I was put on the wrong foot as the text says that this applies for melodic and older. As I was installing noetic I thought it didn't apply anymore. The installation text for noetic says that python 2 is not supported by default anymore so I thought that catkin_make should suffice.

Thanks for all help!

---

Originally posted by [nocom](https://answers.ros.org/users/55199/nocom/) with karma: 81 on 2020-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-05-26**:
Hmm I don't think this is correct; at least I really hope it's not correct. `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3` should not necessary for Noetic on Focal or Buster. `catkin_make` should suffice.

**Comment by [nocom](https://answers.ros.org/users/55199/nocom/) on 2020-05-27**:
I thought so myself but this is what happened in my case. If one needs additional info or tests I am willing to provide.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-05-27**:
I'll do my best to guess. Something has definitely gone wrong. First question, Is Noetic built from source or installed from Debian packages?

The path in the error message `/opt/ros/noetic` suggests it was installed from Debian packages, but if so `ros-noetic-catkin` depends on `python3-empy`, so both would have been installed together. I would have only expected that CMake error message if Noetic was built from source.

**Comment by [acarrillo](https://answers.ros.org/users/7641/acarrillo/) on 2020-12-03**:
I did not build noetic from source in my case -- I am using the `ros:noetic-ros-base-focal` container image and tag. But I did encounter the `Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'.` issue by surprise, and this fix did work for me. To make the matter stranger, I experienced this while working within a container instance that had been running statefully for many days, with plenty of ad-hoc and successful re-compilations, and I abruptly experienced this during a random session!

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-12-03**:
If it happened abruptly in Ubuntu Focal, I would guess the issue is something installed the package `python-is-python2` https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-is-python2 instead of `python-is-python3` https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-is-python3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using Anaconda you can get that error. This installs empy in your Anaconda environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge empy
```

Use your current python for catkin_make (just needed the first time):

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=`which python`
```

Install some dependencies into your Anaconda environment (used in later tutorials):

```
pip install rosdep
```

---

Originally posted by [mangtronix](https://answers.ros.org/users/88940/mangtronix/) with karma: 31 on 2021-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RocaPiedra](https://answers.ros.org/users/64920/rocapiedra/) on 2022-01-09**:
That was my problem, I tried to apt install while using Anaconda and didn't work, this solved it! Thanks a lot

**Comment by [Chops](https://answers.ros.org/users/92017/chops/) on 2022-01-18**:
Thanks, fixed my issue.